# difference between node.js , casper.js and phantom.js?

Tags: web, screen-scraping

I have read these three are used for web scraping . But whats the difference ? in what kind of environment is one better than the other ?

Answer (score 20):

Nodejs is a scripting engine based on Chrome's V8 engine. Nodejs is commonly used as a web server but it is really is a script engine that can run any types of script you like. Node can be used for web scraping by making requests to other servers and then analysing the output.

Phantomjs is a headless webkit browser, which means that it acts just like a browser but doesn't have a UI. Used on its own, it forms a part of a web testing framework but is much better used with...

Casperjs is a utility built on top of Phantomjs that helps you build automated tests.

An automated test can be seen as a web scraper but that's not really what it's for. Web tests are usually sensitive to changes on the page that's being scraped and do not have to be fast at DOM manipulation (because you tend to do one page at a time).

I think nodejs is probably best for what you want.

Comment: thanks for that.. As you say web scraping is my intention. In scraping terms is scrapy better or node.js ?

Comment: Nodejs would be my vote. You can http request someone else's page to scrape and you have JavaScript to work on the DOM. With jquery and underscore libraries (and others), you have a great scraping setup. You Can do it with test automation but you'll be sort of bending it if you want to scrape more than one target. Check your host can run nodejs.

Comment: If JavaScript is required in order for the content you're scraping to get onto the page, just sending HTTP Requests and parsing the responses won't be enough. If you go with Node, you could use jsdom to simulate the DOM. Or you could use PhantomJS or CasperJS (CasperJS is Phantom + more features) to mimic a Web browser. Or use Selenium WebDriver to drive an actual browser.